# Noobish Does Not Exist in the current context

Tags: c#

**Why i cannot call this one? ;(**

```
public void StartNewGame()
{
    Button GamePanelHideButton = new Button();
}

public void GamePanelHideButtonClick()
{
    GamePanelHideButton.Visible = !GamePanelHideButton.visible;
}
```

*GamePanelHideButton does not exist in context :( although its created before.*

Comment: Perhaps you should go run through some very basic C# tutorials before asking questions here?

Comment: Thanks for a help :/

Comment: Find the tutorial that covers "scope".

Comment: Thanks Joe, i got through this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx , and still nothing .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your creation of the button is scoped within startnewgame() and is not accessible to method GamePanelHideButtonClick

Move the GamePanelHideButton variable outside of both methods.

Try this

```cs
public Button GamePanelHideButton;

public void StartNewGame()
{
    GamePanelHideButton = new Button();
}

public void GamePanelHideButtonClick()
{
    GamePanelHideButton.Visible = !GamePanelHideButton.visible;
}
```

Comment: Yep. Seems thats my only easiest way at my beginners level of c#. Thank you very much.

Comment: Although "Public Button GamePanelHideButton;" didnt worked for me.

Comment: I will edit the answer to have the correct public case.

Answer (score 0):

`GamePanelHideButton` is a local variable - it only "exists" while the `StartNewGame` method is actually executing, and the only place you can actually refer to it is from inside the `StartNewGame` method. You should make this a field (class-wide variable).

Also, your statement that "it's created before" it's used is decidedly **not** true (or, at least, not *necessarily* true). There's nothing that'll guarantee that the two methods you show will be executed in any particular order - you could execute them in any order you feel like for all the compiler knows.

Comment: Thank you. I dont really want to create field class just to toggle one boolean property once. Thank you for serious response anyway.

Comment: @DoctorForDeath No need for a separate class - just make it a field of the same class as your methods like Marc has in his answer

Answer (score 0):

Moved this **Button GamePanelHideButton = new Button();** outside any method and it worked, thank u all serious people for help.

```
Button GamePanelHideButton = new Button();
```